# Trouble installing Cyanogen on Galaxy S II using recovery console method

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-2, rom-flashing

After replacing my ailing Nexus One with with a SGS2 yesterday (an ordeal in and of itself, but neither here nor there), I decided to replace the stock  ROM including TouchWiz with something a little more familiar, hence Cyanogen.  I've was following [these](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_II:_Full_Update_Guide) instructions, and it was going relatively well until step 9 under Method via Recovery.  The first time around, I had placed the zip files directly on the root of the SD card, but I couldn't find them.  After several more attempts, using different locations, attempting to put them on the internal storage, etc, I still haven't found a way to load those zip files.

[image: Directory Listing]

As can be seen, I don't have a mount point named sdcard as is typical.  I do have that external_sd folder, but whenever I try and enter it to select a zip, I get an error saying something like "No Files Found" and am just returned to this folder.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The folder you're seeing is the internal SD one. Just put your update.zip file there and search for it, it might be hidden in the scroll, just go down and it will show more files in the folder.

To make the process a lot more easy, just rename your *.zip to update.zip, but the file in the root of the internal SD card folder and use the *Install update.zip from internal SD* method.

Comment: Much thanks.  Still not sure how to put a file there over USB, but using ASTRO File Manager, I made it happen.

Comment: Ahh, nice to see that you made it, it's a pleasure for me to help **:)**

Comment: @MBraedly Your PC should see two drives, one's the internal SD and the other's the external.

Comment: @MatthewRead: I see the 2 drives, but when I was trying this, it wouldn't let me put anything on the internal one.  If I tried putting a file on the root, it would silently fail, if I tried one of the folders, it would say I didn't have permission.  Not sure that's still the case, but I haven't tried since CM7 up and running.